# Why is my transaction not confirming after a month?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees

My Bitcoin transaction 016a647fdb45d0f1a679ae7b3b4465ced76b817f63595c37e3214d63098ddd47

is still unconfirmed. Although I do realise this transaction was made with a low fee 10.044 sat/B, it is not as low that the transaction should not confirm. According to data provided on https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/, this transaction should still confirm within a day.

I tried everything already. I have heard a reset of the wallet may work, however I do not have an actual wallet, but only use the Blockchain.info wallet, where I believe a restart of the wallet is not an option. I also tried rebroadcasting the transaction with various websites, however none of it worked.

What am I supposed to do at this point, that my coins have been stuck in limbo for a month now?

Comment: You may also have a look to this epic thread on delays with tx, and there are some hints further down: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can try is to rebroadcast the transaction and see if you get lucky. You can search for a Bitcoin accelerator and use some of the free ones.

Failing that you can ask a mining pool for some help. For example ViaBTC offer a service described here https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/how-to-accelerate-your-bitcoin-transaction/

And failing that you can create a Child Pays For Parent (CPFP) transaction to increase the fee paid https://bitzuma.com/posts/how-to-clear-a-stuck-bitcoin-transaction/

Answer (score 0):

get the private address of this transactions, install electrum and import this transactions privatekey then you will be able to send this transaction again with no issues.

consider sending it with a higher fee.